# Contiki: undefined reference to a function defined in a separate source file

Tags: c, makefile, contiki

I am writing a program using the Contiki operating system.

I have the `remote_firmware.c` file and a folder called parser with the files `parser.h` and `parser.c` where I wrote the method `void test()`. I included `parser.h` in `remote_firmware.c` with:

```
#include "parser/parser.h"
```

The Makefile looks like this:

```
CONTIKI_PROJECT = remote_firmware
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

#UIP_CONF_IPV6=1

CONTIKI_WITH_RIME = 1
CONTIKI = $(HOME)/contiki

include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

When I try to build this the Error occurs:

> undefined reference to 'test'

I am aware that the Makefile needs to know about `parser.h`, but I do not know how. I tried several solutions which were proposed here but I guess I did something wrong. Maybe somebody of you know what to do?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: to make some line in your question look like 'code', indent the line 4 spaces.  Otherwise, the lines all run together (as you can see in your question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/how-to-fix-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error)

Answer (score 2):

Where is your source file located? Try adding the source file name to the `PROJECT_SOURCEFILES` preprocessor variable (i.e `PROJECT_SOURCEFILES+=parser.c`) and adding the location of the source file to the `CONTIKIDIRS` preprocessor variable (i.e `CONTIKIDIRS+={Directory}`).

If parser.c depends on a lot other C files you might want create an C library archive first and then adding the library to your project by adding the name of the library to the `TARGET_LIBFILES` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The error `undefined reference to test` is an error from the linker not the compiler.  It has nothing to do with including a header file.  It means when you linked the executable you didn't include parser.o

Comment: Yes. Its an issue with the Makefile:

`CONTIKI_PROJECT = remote_firmware
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

#UIP_CONF_IPV6=1
PROJECT_SOURCEFILES += parser/parser.c
CONTIKI_WITH_RIME = 1
CONTIKI = $(HOME)/contiki

include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include`

I added the line 

`PROJECT_SOURCEFILES += parser/parser.c`

But still:
> opening dependency file obj_zoul/parser/parser.d: No such file or directory